# Is there a freeform playing cards deck&table game for Linux?

Tags: games

I am looking for a playing cards "game" where there are no rules and I can just place and move cards as I want. Just a real cards deck and replacement which I can use to play any single-player (solitaire) card game I may know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about totally freeform, but you can try out [PySol](http://www.pysol.org/)

> PySol is an exciting collection of more than 200 solitaire card games.
>   Its features include support for lots
>   of distinct games, very nice look and
>   feel, multiple cardsets and table
>   tiles, sound and background music,
>   unlimited undo & redo, load & save
>   games, player statistics and log
>   files, hint system, demo games,
>   support for user written plug-ins,
>   integrated HTML help browser and lots
>   of documentation.
>
> Among the supported games are classics like Aces Up, Baker's Game,
>   Canfield, FreeCell, Forty Thieves,
>   Golf, Klondike, Pyramid, Scorpion,
>   Spider, Yukon, and many more...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late and a heavy program for what you want but there is now [Tabletop Simulator](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/tabletop-simulator) which is supported on Linux as well as Windows and Mac. It's exactly what you defined and more. You can play cards by yourself or online multi-player without rules  as well as Chess, Checkers, and several other things. The game also supports modding so you can add tabletop pieces if they are not included already.

The reason I say it is "heavy" is that it uses a beautiful full 3D engine that some hardware may struggle with, and since you simply want to play cards, there may be a game based on a 2D engine out there for you.

Side note: it will require you to install the DRM client [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/), I just recommend buying through Humble (linked above) because they donate a portion of all proceeds to charities.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [LackeyCCG](http://www.lackeyccg.com/) which is an app specifically designed for playing collectible card games, but is functional for just about any table top card game. In addition to allowing you to just free form things, you can also generate rules files that determine what you can and can't do in a turn (e.g. draw X cards, play Y cards). It also allows over network play and all sorts of visual and sound customization.